# Write a program using static methods

Tags: java

The problem is as follows:
I have to write a program using static methods which according to what the arguments are like need to return a certain type of information.

1. if the arguments are 2 int-type numbers then it would return the sum of those 2
2. if one of the arguments is a double-type number then it would return that number squared
3. if the arguments are a string and an in-type number then it would print said string times the int-type number.

The problem is that I do not know how exactly this program should look like since there's just one "sample" problem about static methods and that one is nothing like the one I'm being asked to solve.

In addition I still haven't figured out why I even need to use this static method if instead
I could simply write an if sentence instead.

Feels kind of bad to not to be able to figure this out myself but I guess sometimes how have to ask for help.

Anyways thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you looked around online? There are plenty of examples of simple Java programs.  As a hint though, you can have the same method name multiple times which takes different parameters and Java will use the one which is appropriate for the parameters passed.

Comment: `I have to write a program` -- so why are you asking us to do so?

Comment: As usual, I've been trying to play through some examples to get to know how it works and I did a bit of googleing as well but didn't really find any "easy" examples that I could relate to. I will give google another try though and thanks for the tip! @nhgrif I'm really not asking for you to do the work for me, I'm just looking for some tips or anything really that could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so unless I have misunderstood the question want you want to do is overload a method. As a single method in can only accept a fix set of parameters, the way around this would be to create multiple methods (static or otherwise) with the same name but different parameters.

E.g.

```
static int method(int a, int b) {
 return a + b;
}
static double method(double b) {
 return b*b;
}
```

And so on for each different set of parameters required. However I would recommend also looking up this concept thoroughly as its very fundamental.

To add further, an if statement most likely wouldn't evaluate the parameters inside the function correctly most likely be a lot more cumbersome to program than simply overloading your method to accept different types of parameters and act upon them accordingly

Comment: Already fixed this problem. It was ridiculously easy but I just did not know about the fact that if you try to run a static function it would choose to run the one for which your arguments suit.